# Load javascript file from MEF Plugin in MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I am making an MEF/MVC3 application and each plugin has its own javascript file. How should I have the main MEF application access the javascript file from the plugins?

I've tried making the js file an embedded resource and then loading it in the plugin `.vbhtml` like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="@Url.Content("~/bin/CUContractNumberPlugin.dll/CUContractNumberPlugin.CUContractNumberPlugin.js")">
</script>
```

All my plugin DLLs are in the `bin` folder of the main app.

**EDIT:** When my app is loaded into FF, I get a 403 Forbidden error in the Firebug console.

Comment: It works to get js file from embedded resource from your above code?

Comment: @CuongLe: It gives me a 403 Forbidden error in Firebug.